# Changing the default Gitlab port

Tags: gitlab

I have installed the latest Gitlab-CE (8.10) on CentOS 7 (fresh install) via the Omnibus package as described here: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos7

Now, I would like to change the default port at which one can access the Gitlab web interface. To this end, I followed the instructions at http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#change-the-default-port-and-the-ssl-certificate-locations, namely I included

```
external_url "http://127.0.0.1:8765"
```

in the configuration file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and then updated the configuration with `gitlab-ctl reconfigure && gitlab-ctl restart`.

However, when I then navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8765`, Gitlab keeps redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in`, i.e., the port specification is somehow discarded. When I then manually change the URL in the browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8765/users/sign_in`, it correctly displays the login page and interestingly, all links on the page (e.g., "Explore", "Help") contain the port specification.

In order to fix this behavior, is it necessary to specify the port also somewhere else than in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`?

Comment: Strange: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/1210/diffs should have fixed this re the headers properly configured as well? (http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#change-the-default-port-and-the-ssl-certificate-locations)

Comment: @VonC interesting, following your suggestion, I just uncommented the default settings for `nginx['proxy_set_headers']` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` (also, changing `X-Forwarded-Proto` to `http` and removing `X-Forwarded-Ssl`) and suddenly it works! I must have misunderstood the documentation, it seems to suggest that the only thing which needs to be modified is `external_url`.

Comment: Well done! I have added an answer to make that specific part of the documentation more visible.

Comment: Great, thanks! Although I have to admit that I don't fully understand why is this step needed (I am not using a reverse proxy) - the documentation for the https example (changing port from 443 to 2443) states that one can just set `external_url "https://gitlab.example.com:2443"` without any (except the certificates) further modifications

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Issue here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20131
Workaround:
add this line to /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = { "X-Forward-Port" => "8080", "Host" => "<hostname>:8080" }
```

replace port and hostname with your values, then as root or with sudo:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart
```

It helps me on Debian 8.5, gitlab-ce from gitlab repo.

Comment: Thanks! note that the official wiki gives some related information that may be useful: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#change-the-default-proxy-headers

Answer (score 1):

In addition of external_url, the documentation *also* suggests to set a few NGiNX proxy headers:

> By default, when you specify `external_url`, omnibus-gitlab will set a few NGINX proxy headers that are assumed to be sane in most environments.
>
> For example, omnibus-gitlab will set:

```
"X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
"X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
```

> (if you have specified https schema in the `external_url`).
>
> However, if you have a situation where your GitLab is in a more complex setup **like behind a reverse proxy**, you will need to tweak the proxy headers in order to avoid errors like The change you wanted was rejected or Can't verify CSRF token authenticity Completed 422 Unprocessable.
>
> This can be achieved by overriding the default headers, eg. specify in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
 nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "http",
  "CUSTOM_HEADER" => "VALUE"
 }
```

> Save the file and [reconfigure GitLab](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/administration/restart_gitlab.html#omnibus-gitlab-reconfigure) for the changes to take effect.
>
> This way you can specify any header supported by NGINX you require.

The [OP ewcz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5351549/ewcz) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550352/changing-the-default-gitlab-port/38555771#comment64502345_38550352):

> I just uncommented the default settings for `nginx['proxy_set_headers']` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` (also, changing `X-Forwarded-Proto` to `http` and removing `X-Forwarded-Ssl`) and suddenly it works!