# gitlab wrong urls after port change

Tags: url, port, gitlab

I changed my gitlab external address to http://sth.sth.sth:82, everything works properly except sign and creating a new project, these always takes me to http://sth.sth.sth which means the default http port 80, has anyboady an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38563621/6309 could help?

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: What version of GitLab are you using? On which platform?

Comment: my real address is http://intranet.procus.sk:82/gitlab, everytime i open it, I get redirected to http://intranet.procus.sk/gitlab/users/sign_in

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, gitlab 8.10.0

Comment: as I can see, it's an issue of gitlab and should be fixed in next version, but I would need some workaround till it;s fixed

Comment: Do you have a link? By next version, do you mean GitLab 8.11?

Comment: I reconfigured it few more times with same settings and it suddenly works, I guess there are things between linux and heaven, thank you very much :)